# composition of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm given that $g(z)= \ln r+i\theta$ where $(r>0,0<\theta<2\pi)$ . I've already shown this function is analytic and that its derivative is $g'(z)=\frac{1}{z}$. Now it wants me to show $G(z)=g(z^2+1)$ is analytic where $x,y>0$ but what I don't get is what the output of $g(z^2+1)$ looks like.
I know that $z=re^{i\theta}\implies z^2=r^2e^{i2\theta}\implies z^2+1=r^2e^{i2\theta}+1$. Then $g(z^2+1)=g(r^2e^{i2\theta}+1)$? From here I just dont see what the output would be. Is it $g(r^2e^{i2\theta}+1)=\ln r^2+i2\theta$?

Comment: Please consider using \ln to get $\ln$ instead of $ln$.

Comment: I was unsure how to do the second part of this as well, as I too thought of what the output should be. Then I figured out a simpler way. If you can show the analyticity of both g(z) and z^2+1 by checking the continuity of partials as well as the Cauchy Reimann equations, then it follows that the composition of two analytic functions is in fact analytic as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $g(z^2+1) = g(r^2e^{2i\theta}+1)$.

But, $g(z^2+1)$ is more complicated than 
 $$\ln(r^2) + 2i\theta$$ (which is $2g(z)$ btw), you have forgoten the "+1".

I don't think this output is relevant: let $H^+=\{z\in \mathbb C ; y>0, x>0\}$ and $\Omega=\mathbb C \setminus \{z\in \mathbb C ; \theta \equiv 0 [2pi]\}$. So $$f:H^+ \to \Omega, z\mapsto z^2+1$$ and $$g:\Omega \to \mathbb C$$ are both analytics.

So the composed function $g  o f$ is analytic. You just have to show properly that $f(H^+) \subset \Omega$.